# Use Enter Key Act Like Tab Key on jTable

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtable, enter

I'm stuck from 2 days in my project i cant implement how to make the **ENTER KEY** act like **TAB KEY**  i tried **key listener** but the ENTER KEY have a default feature for JTable so it's not working it's keep moving down. I [google](http://google.com) it discovered that i need to use **key binding** but i'm unable to implement it.

Can anyone give me a full coded example of this on a JTable ??? Please need you help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: despite the fact that it is possible, I'm wouldn't be lock ENTER key for next cell, you have to (complicate) override stopCellEditing for TableCellEditor, don't to confuse a users, let it be for whales and to use standards, the same commands are in MsExcel etc...

Comment: i want to use the enter key as i want to restrict the number of key used !! by pressing enter move next cell and preform any action like click a button !!

Comment: why shouting, sure this decision is just and only up_to_you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic twist would be to use the key bindings API, which will allow you to override, in most cases, the default behaviour keys on many components.

This example basically applies the same named action to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys, this makes it easy to modify their behaviour through the use of a single `Action`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test101();
    }

    public Test101() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTable table = new JTable();
                InputMap im = table.getInputMap();
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Action.NextCell");
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "Action.NextCell");

                ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
                am.put("Action.NextCell", new NextCellActioin(table));

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(10, 10);
                table.setModel(model);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class NextCellActioin extends AbstractAction {

        private JTable table;

        public NextCellActioin(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
            int rowCount = table.getRowCount();

            col++;
            if (col >= colCount) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }

            if (row >= rowCount) {
                row = 0;
            }

            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(col, col);
        }

    }

}
```

The functionality of <kbd>Tab</kbd> is controlled by changing the default focus behaviour through the focus manager as I recall

Comment: I'm using netbeans so how i should initialize 
`JTable table = new JTable();
 InputMap im = table.getInputMap();
 im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0),"Action.NextCel");
 im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB,0),"Action.NextCell");
 ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
 am.put("Action.NextCell", new NextCellActioin(table));`

Comment: I wrote the example in NetBeans, do you mean you use the form editor?

Comment: in your example 
`public Test101() {}` it's the initialization section i can't edit it normally i have to use custom code in the design!!

Comment: Okay, so you will have a reference of a `JTable` somewhere in your code (it defaults to something like `jtable1` for example).  After the `initComponents` method is called in the classes constructor, you should apply the key bindings, using the reference of your `JTable` in place of my `table`

Comment: another thing when i was working with the tab key normal way!! i was skipping the last column and inserting a new row !! everything is working fine but the new row is not selecting it self automatically !!
`setRowSelectionInteral()` is throwing null point exception !!

Comment: Post code, in fact, it might better to post another question. It clutters the the current post

Answer (score 4):

```
    KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
    KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
    InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    im.put(enter, im.get(tab));
```

Comment: `im.get(tab)` returns `null`.  As I recall, the `JTable` modifies the default focus transversal behaviour through the [focus sub system](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, JTable uses a custom Action to do tabbing between table cells. Check out my [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) programs that lists all the default bindings. The key is to use the "ancestor" InputMap to get the identifier for the tab KeyStroke.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the behavior at the action map and input map of the `JTable`:

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
Object actionKey = new Object();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), actionKey);
table.getActionMap().put(actionKey, new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // Do something for ENTER
    }
});
```

The default behavior you talk about is present in the action map, initialized by default.

Comment: As I recall, the `JTable` modifies the default focus transversal behaviour through the [focus sub system](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), TAB is not controlled through the key bindings

Comment: I do nothing here with the Tab key. The question was about the ENTER key and that is what I use here.

Comment: I assumed your reference to the default behaviour was directed at the tab key