# Inserted Row Selection jTable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable

I have a JTable that inserts an empty row when ever i tab out the 2nd last column this works fine. I also added `table.setRowSelectionInterval(lastRow,lastRow);` to select my new inserted row at the same time but it throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Need help to select the last inserted row. Thanks in Advance.

```
public class JFrameTable extends javax.swing.JFrame {

protected JTable table;


public JFrameTable() {
    initComponents();

}

public  void setValueAt(int col){
     DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    if(col==2){
       Vector row = new Vector();
       row.add(null);
       row.add(null);
       row.add(null);
       row.add(null);

     model.addRow(row);
    }
}



private class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    public MyKeyListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_TAB){
            int column = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
            int rowCount= jTable1.getRowCount();
            int currentRow=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
            if(currentRow==rowCount-1) {
                jTable1.editCellAt(currentRow, column);
                jTable1.transferFocus();
           }
           if(column==3 && currentRow==rowCount-1){
                setValueAt(2);
           }
           if(column==3){
              currentRow++;
              column=0;
              jTable1.editCellAt(currentRow, column);
              jTable1.transferFocus();
          try{                
              table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount-1,rowCount-1);
          }catch(Exception ek){
              System.out.println(ek);
          } 
          }
           System.out.println(rowCount);
          }

    }
     @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
     @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}

private class MySelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    public MySelectionListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    }
}


private class setTableModelListener implements TableModelListener{
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

}
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTable1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(75, 107, 221));
    jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 1, 15)); // NOI18N
    jTable1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(254, 247, 247));
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Name", "Roll", "Stream", "Sex"
        }
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            true, true, true, false
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new setTableModelListener());
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    jTable1.setRowHeight(20);
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font ("SansSerif", Font.BOLD ,15));
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new MySelectionListener());
    jTable1.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
    jTable1.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(30);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 630, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 205, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JFrameTable().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration                   
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the codes please?

Comment: Not exaclty full code but those parts which creates you problem

Comment: i have posted the full code

Comment: @Pappu 1. :-) have to returns back to your [1st question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648646/use-enter-key-act-like-tab-key-on-jtable), 2. don't to use `KeyListener` for `JTable`, this is major issue, 3. second is strange if inside `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {`, to move everything those code lines to ListSelectionListener, because those event haven't something with KeyListener, 4. again don't to confuse users, Mouse and Key Events should be the same, otherwise you have to override Mouse Events too, to try to avoid to create a mess

Comment: @mKorbel you are right at some point !! im agreed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong...

1. Avoid `KeyListener`, there are a swagger of problems associated with using `KeyListener`s which the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) fixes
2. You select the row by using `table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount-1,rowCount-1);`, but `rowCount` is no longer valid, as you've added a new row
3. `transferFocus` is used to transfer focus to the next focusable component, which will mean that the `JTable` would mostly likely lose focus, pretty sure this isn't what you want.

For example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(4, 4);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                InputMap im = table.getInputMap();
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "CellAction");

                ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
                am.put("CellAction", new CellAction(table));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CellAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JTable table;

        public CellAction(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
            int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
            int currentRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (currentRow == rowCount - 1) {
                table.editCellAt(currentRow, column);
            }
            if (column == 3 && currentRow == rowCount - 1) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                Vector row = new Vector();
                row.add(null);
                row.add(null);
                row.add(null);
                row.add(null);

                model.addRow(row);
            }
            if (column == 3) {
                currentRow++;
                column = 0;
                table.setRowSelectionInterval(currentRow, currentRow);
                table.setColumnSelectionInterval(column, column);
                table.editCellAt(currentRow, column);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `table.setRowSelectionInterval(currentRow, currentRow);
                table.setColumnSelectionInterval(column, column);
                table.editCellAt(currentRow, column);`
after inserting new row the currentRow is getting reset !! i mean after inserting new row if the currentRow is now 1 the it's reseting to 0 :(

Comment: hey thanks a lot @MadProgrammer you idea of using `ActionMap` & `InputMap` mad it possible !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem in misspelling, just change

`table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount-1,rowCount-1);` to

`jTable1.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount-1,rowCount-1);`.

Because `table` is null. And everywhere you use `jTable1`.

Comment: it's not throwing null point exception now but not selecting the new inserted row !!